# help me make a bi-directional motor circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, dc-motor, bidirectional

the first circuit is supposed to make the motor moves clockwise and anti clock wise according to the potentiometer.
the figure's components are
IC1: 741 op-amp
Q1: TIP3055 NPN
Q2: MJE34 PNP (yea it's written PNP but it's NPN in proteus 8)

it didn't worked so it has been redesigned as shown in the second figure
IC1: 741 op-amp
Q1: TIP3055 NPN
Q2: MJE350 PNP

the different result was that the motor is now moving anticlockwise. any edits to make it move in the two directions ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like you already found the answer! This is not a design service.

Answer (score 1):

For reference, here is your circuit that is being discussed:

[image]

Your double emitter follower is a valid approach for a low power motor.

But, the way you're driving the bases makes little sense.  Tie the bases together and drive them directly from the opamp output.  I can't guess what you think the resistors are supposed to accomplish.  Then take the feedback from the motor voltage, not the opamp output.  It's the motor voltage you're trying to control.

### After schematic update

Here is the schematic we are now discussing:

[image]

Problems:

You didn't connect the controlled power voltage to the motor!  The purpose of the double emitter follower is to provide current gain for driving the motor.  The output of this current amplifier is the two emitters connected together.  That's what should be driving the top side of the motor.

All you have connected is the feedback signal, which isn't able to drive anything.

You eliminated the negative supply!  I can't even guess why you think that was a good idea.  I didn't mention anything about the negative supply before since it was fine.  Of course you can only drive the motor in one direction if one side is grounded and all the other voltages are positive.  You have left no way to apply a negative voltage to the motor.

A 741 opamp is a poor choice.  You have only a 9 V supply.  The emitter follower will drop 700 mV or so, and this opamp can't go all the way to the rails.  With a ±9 V supply, you should at least get some results, though.

Go back to the original circuit and try what I said.

Comment: i did what you said, the different result i got was that the motor is now moving anti clockwise unlike the old design that used to move clockwise. and varying the potentiometer just affects the motor's speed as the maximum speed was at 50%. i can't attach the redesigned circuit's image here so please take a look at http://i.imgur.com/ToUTFed.png (the edited wires are blue-colored)
if there are any other edits you wanna me apply it, just tell me. thanks for your comment, your help is really appreciated.

Comment: @Oev: Update your question with the schematic exactly how you built it.  From your brief description, it seems like the driver on one side isn't connected up right.  Check all the connections on the transistor towards the power suppy in the dircection the motor won't turn.

Comment: check the new update, please.

Answer (score 0):

The 1K resistors limit your base current to around 8mA max.  According to the datasheet, the gain of the TIP3055 may be as low as 20.  Which limits your total output current to your motor to as little as 160mA.  In the best case you would be limited to delivering no more than 0.36W to your motor.

I would suggest removing the 1K gate resistors.  Your first circuit would probably work with just that change.

If you want to control the motor voltage more precisely you can connect the inverting input of the op-amp to the emitters of Q1 and Q2 instead of their bases.  That way the feedback is taken at the motor rather than at the transistor bases.  Taking the feedback at the bases results in an extra +/-0.7V of error in your output voltage.

Comment: @Olin Lathrop i think it was a way easier for you to draw the working diagram ! i can't understand you man, i'm beginner and this is my first project !